Document to prove a genuine relationship
What type of documentation should I provide to prove friendship with my sponsor for a UK standard visa? Screenshots of our chat or what kind?

While the bank statements are very much more likely to be the reason a visa is given or denied, they do not replace relationship proof.

You can provide a simple letter written by your friend who is from UK

I don't think you can just prove 'friendship'. Chat screenshots is not going to make it. A cover letter mentioning that you are close friends will be ok. You don't have to prove it.
That being said, your finances matter. If you don't have much financial ability and your friend sponsors your trip entirely, that is very suspicious. According to the UK, you are likely to overstay or work illegally.
Say you can handle airfare and other expenses from your finances, without digging into your savings significantly. Your friend just provides you with accommodation, then it is a normal case (I got a visa based on that). Then, the friend is no longer a full sponsor. You are funding your own trip and the friend is hosting you.
See this answer also.

Thank you so much for your answer. Yes, I think it is better. So, What is the exact amount we will need to prove in our bank statement if we choose to follow your case? (that we pay for our flight and that the friend just welcomes us). It is just for 3 weeks. I mean, how many should we estimate our trip.
It is our first application, so we really need help

@Brenda There is no fixed number. You should be able to afford the trip comfortably with your savings. That's all.

@Brenda If it’s an internet friend whom you’ve never met in person, forget it. IMHO an application on that basis will be refused. You need an invitation from your sponsor inviting you to stay and explaining why they are inviting you. There are a lot of questions about UK visas here https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4347/uk-visas-overview-community-wiki-to-avoid-duplicates

Can you also suggest me some tips to avoid a refusal please?

Yes, we met on facebook for a long time. And he would like to receive my bf and I at his home when we will arrive in UK. Basically it's supposed to be a romantic trip for me and my boyfriend, but he kindly offered to host us at his place since we've known each other for a year. We therefore pay our flight costs and our activities during our stay, but he will simply take care of our accommodation . Do we have a chance of getting the visa with these conditions? @Traveller

@Brenda Read this. IMHO, if your profile is young, single, no children or dependents (eg parents who require your presence to take care of them), and no prior travel history, forget it. You’re almost certainly going to get a refusal, and having an ‘internet friend’ sponsor is vanishingly unlikely to change that.

So what is the best thing to do in my case? @Traveller

@Brenda If by that you mean ‘yes, that’s an accurate description of my profile’ then you need to save more, and build up a travel history to other destinations. Meanwhile have your online friend visit you a few times in your home country. Or you can apply for the visa and see what happens.

Basically we're not coming for our friend, it's supposed to be a romantic trip with my boyfriend to celebrate our anniversary, our friend is just hosting us. Would it not then be possible to make this trip? @Traveller

@Brenda No-one can answer that with certainty. UKVI will grant or refuse your visa depending on their assessment of whether you meet the UK’s Suitability, Eligibility, and Genuine Visitor Immigration Rules. The only way to know for sure if you can make the trip or not is to apply. But if you don’t have any prior travel history, if I were you I’d pick somewhere else for your romantic trip. There is a lot of advice and questions on this topic on TSE. Ask a new question if none of it helps.

Yes I understand. Uk is our dream destination since a long time, and now we can realise this dream so we want to do our best to get a visa. @Traveller

@Brenda, all your recent questions show you are not very likely to get a visa. Getting a refusal now will getting one in the next few years much harder.

In an earlier question, you said your Internet friend is paying for  "our flight, our visa and our accommodation during the stay". What changed? And why are they being so generous? Are you being scammed or risk getting trapped somehow?

We have been very good friends for a long time. My boyfriend and I planned to come there for a romantic trip and they kindly offered us accommodation, and even a flight. But all things considered, we would like to pay for our flights ourselves. So, would this pose so much of a problem? Is our situation not good for obtaining a visa?
We have a job and we only have a month off to be able to make this trip so we plan to make the most of it. Does everything you say mean that we will never be able to obtain our visa? What should we do? @lambshaanxy

what should we do? Look at the UK’s Rules and read their Visit guidance. Assess your personal circumstances against that information. Apply for the visa only if you truly believe you meet all the criteria and have documentation to prove that. Do not apply if you conclude you don’t meet all the criteria. As @Willeke commented, your various questions indicate your chances of getting a visa are not good. Even more so if you are from a high immigration risk country eg Nigeria

The graphic in this question shows how visa-issuing authorities are likely to risk assess an application
